# Sending Push Notification from Ionic using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to send a notification to multiple users when there is update in my app.

Based on this guide, https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase I can able to send notification.

But this is not automated.

How do i send notification automatically from my code ?

Below is what I've done so far,

```
ngOnInit(): void {


    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(result => {
      if (result.receive === 'granted') {
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        PushNotifications.register();
      } else {
        // Show some error
      }
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
      (token: Token) => {
        messaging.getToken({vapidKey: token.value});

        alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
      }
    );

     // Some issue with our setup and push will not work
     PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError',
     (error: any) => {
       alert('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
     }
   );


   PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived',
   (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
     alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
   }
 );

  // Method called when tapping on a notification
  PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed',
  (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
    alert('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
  }
);
}
```

Comment: how do you know there is an Update available??

Comment: I've this `function firebase.database().ref(`drivers/${user.uid}`).on("value", snap => {}` when this triggers I've to send a push notification

Comment: if you are using firebase you can use firebase cloud Function to send Push notification.

Comment: can you provide some sample code for reference